# asp.net mvc Razor partial view: no intellisense or colors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i created a Razor partial view in visual studio 2010

it added it as .cshtml file. It actually works, but development in it kind of sucks because the whole file is black on white, like notepad. no colors for html markup, and no intellisense.

I also looked at the sample views that were added when i created a new Razor project. They're all black on white.

as per Jon's suggestion i uninstalled MVC 3, and all its VS Tools components, and re-installed the RC, restarted PC and VS. Still no intelisense and color in Razor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the ASP.NET MVC 3 Release Candidate installed?  Razor Intellisense was only added in the RC.  (See [ScottGu's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx))

Comment: Has it ever worked?  Try uninstalling whatever you have installed (see http://drew-prog.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-uninstall-microsoft-aspnet-mvc-3.html) and installing the RC to make sure it IS the one you have...

Comment: Did you uninstall the previous versions of MVC3 (Beta and/or Preview 1)? You can also see if you've got RC if the cshtml icons are nice and not all white.

Comment: hmm did not check the icons after re-install.. will do this evening when i get home, thanks